# Is there a way of bringing over a value of i = 0 to another Python file?

Tags: python

I have a file named FileA.py that has a variable a = 0. 
I have another file named FileB.py which has a variable b = a and that a is referring to the value of a in FileA.py. 
Is there any way that I can read/import the value of a in FileA.py to FileB.py and hence making variable b = 0?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the content of `fileA.py`:

```
a = 0
```

Here is the content of `fileB.py`:

```
from fileA import a

b = a
print(b) # --> 0
```

When running `fileB` it first imports the variable `a` (and its value) from `fileA`, then uses it to initialize variable `b`. This is confirmed by the final `print` which outputs `0`

Answer (score 0):

1. Use global scope method, reference below:
   https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-keyword-in-python/amp/
2. Use import method example:
   FileA.py
   a=0

FileB.py
import FileA

b=FileA.a

3. You can use script FileB.py from FileA.py and read the input “a” as an argument.

Hope this helps.